# How to get started with URL Routing in an asp.net webform application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

Thus far working with asp.net `webforms` was very easy .... But never implemented `URL Routing` in webforms... I know asp.net MVC Handles URL Routing pretty well...

How to get started with URL Routing in an asp.net webform application?

**For EX:**

Say http://www.mydomain.com/Forms/Category.aspx i want it to be like http://www.mydomain.com/Forms/Category

Any good article to start with URL Routing asp.net 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [**Using ASP.NET Routing Without ASP.NET
  MVC**](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx)
- [**Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)
- [**Using Routing With WebForms**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx). by Phil Hack
- [**ASP.NET Routing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

hope this helps